# A Diffrent HA Approach for Multi master Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, high-availability

We have a client that has 3 nodes in different locations and different network subnets. They want to use our product with HA mode. We tell them that to run our product on HA mode we need to use an external load balancer or they need to put all the nodes in the same subnet using technologies like VXLAN.

Kubernetes advice for the HA environment is to use an external load balancer or keepalived and haproxy pair for the bare-metal solution.

But they denied all of them. So my boss told me to find an average solution for that situation. So I find a solution but I need to know the bottlenecks, cons, or possible bugs for this. Here is my solution:

```
# My nodes:
Node-1 192.168.10.100/24  <---- This is my initial master
Node-2 192.168.20.100/24
Node-3 192.168.30.100/24
```

- I added the `192.168.10.100 kubernetes.company.internal` record to the `/etc/hosts` file on all master nodes
- Init the cluster on the initial master using the following command: `kubeadm init --upload-certs --control-plane-endpoint kubernetes.company.internal:6443 --pod-network-cidr 172.244.0.0/16`
- Then join the other 2 nodes to the cluster as a master
- After the other 2 nodes successfully joined the cluster I modified the records inside the `/etc/hosts` file for the point to the node's own IP address. Then I restarted the node
- I removed the taints from the master nodes except the initial one so k8s schedule workloads on these nodes

After this operation, I performed a bunch of HA tests and all of them seemed to be successful. I confirmed they are not planning the add more nodes to the cluster as a worker. All of the machines are capable of running more workloads in case of one node failure.

My question is what are the bottlenecks, cons, or possible bugs for this kind of setup?

Comment: When you say your product is it just an application or a database..? In the title you have mentioned as multi master configuration, does it mean in each region you have a master and worker nodes or the master node itself is acting like both master and worker, also have you configured any storage or database replication..?

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni My product consists of a bunch of microservices running on Kubernetes. The Database and replication were done by the customer itself and we are using it. We are using Longhorn for the storage layer. Yes, my nodes act like both master and worker. We removed the NoSchedule taints from the master nodes except the initial one(it does not have a decent amount of resources like memory and CPU for running services).